# Convert JAX-RS resultset to array no loop

Tags: java, arrays, list, jax-rs

I want to convert the resultset to json list but the result just show for 1 row:

result:

{"kodekasus":70,"nama":"string","isdelete":0,"createdby":"string","createddate":"2017-06-29","updatedby":"string","updateddate":"2017-06-29"}

controller:

```
@GET
@Path("/tes")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Kasuss getTest() throws SQLException {
    String sqlquery = "Select * from Kasus";
    dbCon = new DBConnection();

    try{
        conn = DBConnection.setDBConnection();
        rs = dbCon.getResultSet(sqlquery, conn);
        Kasuss kasus = new Kasuss();

        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        ArrayList<Kasuss> list = new ArrayList<Kasuss>();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while(rs.next()){
                kasus.setKodekasus(rs.getInt(1));
                kasus.setNama(rs.getString(2));
                kasus.setIsdelete(rs.getInt(3));
                kasus.setCreatedby(rs.getString(4));
                kasus.setCreateddate(rs.getDate(5));
                kasus.setUpdatedby(rs.getString(6));
                kasus.setUpdateddate(rs.getDate(7));
                list.add(kasus);
            }               
            return kasus;

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

in database record, not just one record. How to show the list array result? not just one row record.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to receive all records instead of one your method return type should be a collection, e.g.

```
public Collection<Kasuss> getTest() throws SQLException {
```

and you need to return the `list` var not the `kasus` one.